# Django + Celery + Scrapy twisted reactor(ReactorNotRestartable) and database(SSL error) errors

Tags: python, django, scrapy, celery, twisted

I have a Django 2.0, Celery 4 and Scrapy 1.5 setup where I have a Spider inside a django custom command and I need to call this command at regular intervals, I use Celery to call these commands and they involve scraping a web page and saving some results to the database. Here are my files:

**get_data.py**

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Crawl for new data'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        settings = Settings()
        settings.setmodule(crawler_settings)
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings=settings)
        args = {some needed args}
        process.crawl(DataLogSpider, kwargs=args)
        process.start()
```

**celery.py**

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.local')

app = Celery('config')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**tasks.py**

```
@task()
def collect_data_information():
    call_command('get_data')
```

**(Django) settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-get-logs': {
        'task': 'core.tasks.collect_data_information',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/15')  # every 15 minutes
    },
}
```

I've removed some imports and reduced the code for simplicity. The problem is that when I run my celery task, my spider will only execute the first time, the second time I get `ReactorNotRestartable` error. I understand that the problem comes from the Twisted reactor being restarted more than once, which is not possible. I've already looked into these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495052/scrapy-reactor-not-restartable), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946632/reactornotrestartable-error-in-while-loop-with-scrapy), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849715/running-more-than-one-spider-in-a-for-loop) and many others involving the same error, but none of them considered the concurrency problem when using Django to save to the database.

When I tried applying their solution to my problem I receive a `django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac`. I've looked that up as well and it is caused by the multiple processes that open a database connection, which is actually hapenning because of their solution.

So my question boils down to: `Is there a way to run Celery+Scrapy+Django without having problems with the Twisted reactor being opened and finished multiple times?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution myself. I had to add the following to by celery settings file:

```
app.conf.update(
    worker_max_tasks_per_child=1,
    broker_pool_limit=None
)
```

This tells celery to start every task with a clean slate, therefore every task will be started in a new process and the ReactorNotRestartable problem won't occur.

Comment: My 2 cents: This configuration makes Celery start a new process for every task, that can be resource-intensive and slow down the performance of your system.

Do you have this configuration running in production?